# logging.level.root doesn't work in springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I want to setting the default logging level to error on springboot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Zp9.png)

But the console still has the dubug and info output. It seems that logging.level.root=error doesn't work.

Comment: Do you run with `--debug` or `debug=true` or debug enabled in the run configuration?  As that appears to be the case judging from the output.

Comment: I just run the project by "run as springboot" in eclipse.
Emm... How can I know if I run the project with the debug mode?

Comment: Check the configuration that is being generated. Judging from the output (the report etc) you have debug enabled.

Comment: Hello,I debug the source code and found that the springboot sets the logging level to "debg"  for some packages,such as "org.springframework.boot" by default,which occurs before the logging level set for the root(error).If this behavior correct?If not,how can I change the behavior?I just want to log the error messages.

Comment: It doesn't do that by default it does that when you start with `--debug` or `debug=true` in your properties. I suspect that this is part of your `Run Configuration` in Eclipse. Or the fact that Spring Devtools is part of your application (have you tried removing that?).

Comment: I can sure I don't use the --debug or debug=true.
I also try to remove the devtools and the result still doesn't chage.I change the logging.level.root to "debug" and find a exception "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException".

Comment: The fact that you don't explicitly use it doesn't mean that it isn't automatically done by Eclipse for instance. I have no idea what a Run As does in Eclipse when using Spring Boot (especially when using STS for instance, that could add it by default).

Comment: I found a environment variable named debug,even though its value is a string not true,which caused the problem.Actually,I tried to remove the variable before,but I didn't restart the eclipse.Now,I remove the varibale named DEBUG and restart the eclipse,and it success.

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull if you are using Spring Boot Devtools, the properties defined in `$HOME/.config/spring-boot` folder will override all other properties as specified in Spring Boot documentation : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html

Comment: I remove the devtools from the pom file of my project and set the logging.level.root=error but the info and debug messages still show.

BTW,I also try to add  "spring.devtools.add-properties=false" in the application.properties,but the info and debug messages still show

Comment: Hello,I debug the source code and found that the springboot sets the logging level to "debg"  for some packages,such as "org.springframework.boot" by default,which occurs before the logging level set for the root(error).If this behavior correct?If not,how can I change the behavior?I just want to log the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I found a environment variable named debug,even though its value is a string not true,which caused the problem.Actually,I tried to remove the variable before,but I didn't restart the eclipse.Now,I remove the varibale named DEBUG and restart the eclipse,and it success.